# How to set jLabel to output multiple loops

Tags: loops, label

I'm working on a homework assignment, which requires me to make a program that counts. The example given is

```
int i = 1;
while (i <= 5){
     System.out.println(i);
     i++;
}
```

Now, I have everything working, except I need to assign the output to a label, what I have is.

```
while (start <= end) {
        outputLabel.setText(String.valueOf(start));
        start++;
    }
}
```

When I run it, all it displays is the end number. I figure this is because the label is reset every time it loops, instead of displaying all the loops. How can I make it show every number instead of just the last number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add the number to the text of the label:

```
outputLabel.setText(outputLabel.getText() + start);
```

The System.out.println doesn't make sense for me at all.